# How to map Axios get response to array

Tags: javascript, axios

I have tried numerous variations based on other questions on this site but I cannot seem to get my response correctly mapped into my array.

Tried with/without JSON.Parse , tried using responseType: 'json' in headers of GET, tried using response and response.data

```
function getNotificationsForDevice() {
  var MAC_ADDRESS = document.getElementById("DeviceInput").value;
  var regexp = /^(([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}[:]){5}[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}[,]?)+$/i;

  var DeviceAlertE = document.getElementById("DeviceAlert");
  var notifications = [];

  if (regexp.test(MAC_ADDRESS)) {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:56005/api/Notifications", {
        //responseType: 'json',
        params: {
          MacAddress: MAC_ADDRESS
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        const newNotification = {
          id : res.data.ID,
          destination : res.data.Destination,
          MacAddress : res.data.MAC_ADDRESS
        };
        notifications.push(newNotification);      
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    DeviceAlertE.innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    alert("Invalid MAC Address");
  }
  localStorage.setItem("notifications", JSON.stringify(notifications));
  fetchNotifications();
}
```

notifications array is always empty instead of getting the data retruned from the GET.

EDIT: 
Get response​ shown below

0: {…}
​​
Destination: "email1@gmail.com"
​​
Id: 1
​​
MacAddress: "f8:f0:05:ed:1d:28"
​​
SendAlertTypes: "0,1,2,3,4,5,6"
​​
: Object { … }
​
1: {…}
​​
Destination: "email2@hotmail.com"
​​
Id: 6
​​
MacAddress: "f8:f0:05:ed:1d:28"
​​
SendAlertTypes: "0,1,2,3,4,5,6"
​​
: Object { … }
​
2: {…}
​​
Destination: "email3@vtext.com"
​​
Id: 14
​​
MacAddress: "f8:f0:05:ed:1d:28"
​​
SendAlertTypes: "0,1,2,3,4,5,6"
​​
: {…

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. We cannot see the response so there's zero way to know what to do with it once you have it. Note that you could simply `console.log` the response so *you* can see what you have (or use the debugger) and decide what to do with it once you know what you're working with.

Comment: Have you tried logging the contents of `res` to make sure you're getting the data as expected? Add `console.log(res)` before your `newNotification` initialization and add the output to your question.

Comment: I updated question to include a textual copy/paste console.log(res.data)

Comment: your pasted response there looks a little garbled... but it looks to me that res.data is a JSON array... have you tried checking to see what 
`res.data.ID`
returns? My guess would be `undefined`.  Your data looks like an array to me... I'd be willing to bet that you could smply take res.data and simply shove it into notifications as-is and return it (unless all you really need is just the ID, destination, and MacAddress, then simply copy just that part)... but bottom line is you'er looking in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 2):

You are saving the notifications array in the localStorage before actually filling that array. You should do something like this:

```
function getNotificationsForDevice() {
  var MAC_ADDRESS = document.getElementById("DeviceInput").value;
  var regexp = /^(([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}[:]){5}[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}[,]?)+$/i;

  var DeviceAlertE = document.getElementById("DeviceAlert");
  var notifications = [];

  if (regexp.test(MAC_ADDRESS)) {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:56005/api/Notifications", {
        //responseType: 'json',
        params: {
          MacAddress: MAC_ADDRESS
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        const newNotification = {
          id : res.data.ID,
          destination : res.data.Destination,
          MacAddress : res.data.MAC_ADDRESS
        };
        notifications.push(newNotification);
        // Moved code here so you have the notifications array with your request's data
        localStorage.setItem("notifications", JSON.stringify(notifications));
        fetchNotifications();
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    DeviceAlertE.innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    alert("Invalid MAC Address");
  }
}
```

Comment: I think instead of my array being equal to [] it is now [{}]

Comment: Try logging your response now, it seems like the notification is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to map a resonse that was an array into my array. I ended up looping on the response to get the data I needed to populate individual objects and then push to array...